# Not able to run the nightwatch scripts because of Run.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am getting the following error while running the nightwatch code : **"An error occurred while trying to start the Nightwatch Runner: Cannot find module 'nightwatch/lib/runner/run'"**

Earlier when I used to install npm, it used to download the run file inside node-modules->nightwatch -> lib ->bin ->runner, but from past 5,6 days when I am installing npm it is not installing the run file inside runner and scripts are failing mentioning the above error.

I tried to run command as *nightwatch --tag tagname*

Can Anyone let me know why this error is coming now, as previously it used to run fine?? Is there is any change in nightwatch configurations??

Answer (score -1):

This failure could be because of release of version 1.x of Nightwatch. Please try to downgrade Nightwatch to `0.9.21` and then it should work fine.